# Is there a class or library for creating calendars?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I need a calendar in my app where the user can pick a date from. I wonder if there's a calendar library to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the documentation on the NSCalender class in Foundation? I doubt that the NSCalender class will actually draw out or manage a calender for you graphically but it appears to provide functionality to help with the headache of calculating things like leap-years and such. I have not used this class myself yet but I have played around with NSDate and it is very convenient. There might exist a class that can help you draw / layout a graphic calender though... **[Update]** I found a tutorial where someone modified a calender project from Google Code to create a calender and then explained how he did it. See these links:

TUTORIAL:
http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244

ORIGINAL GOOGLE CODE PROJECT (KLCalender Class)
http://code.google.com/p/kcalendar-iphone/

REFERENCE:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html

DATE & TIMEPROGRAMMING GUIDE:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html