# How to create a calendar in Iphone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa-design-patterns

I had developed a website application which consists a calendar used to record member's events. So, I need to develop an Iphone Application. For example, this Iphone Application consists of 4 tabs, when click on one tab, it will show a calendar which is equal to the corresponding calendar in that website application I had developed.

Therefore, does anyone know how to add or create a calendar view in an Iphone application?

Really appreciate for any suggestions and solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Similar question with quite good answers is here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348971/is-there-a-class-or-library-for-creating-calendars

Answer (score 2):

You can find one in tapku library. it is open source and available on github here is the URL

https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...its quite easy to use and flexible to edit as per your usage.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal